# how to make params that automatically scrolls to a section

Tags: vue.js, parameters

I want to have a route like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/help/category/newuser#1
```

Therefore, I write this in my template

```
<router-link
   v-bind:to="{
   name: 'help',
   params: { id: selectedCategory+'#'+eachQuestion.id },
   }"
>
```

But this doesn't work and resulting in

```
http://localhost:8080/help/category/newuser%231
```

So the `#` turns into `%23`. How to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Your route should have the parameters named, for instance: `help/:category/:id`, so you can pass the params in this way: `params: { category: selectedCategory, id: eachQuestion.id }`

Comment: Agree with @Ohgodwhy but if you are trying to concat a string for a url use `encodeURIComponent()` and decode it on the other side. or, you know... just use a hyphen.

Comment: The `#1` is an id of a section of the page. So I want to go to `http://localhost:8080/help/category/newuser` and then automatically scrolls to the section with the corresponding id, which in this example is id 1. @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to a route with params by passing the param names as an object:

```
params: { category: selectedCategory }
```

If you are also passing a `hash` value, you're able to declare the `hash` property as well:

```
hash: eachQuestion.id
```